# Extracting system call name and arguments using ptrace

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I am working on an assignment in which i have to implement `strace` like functionality using `ptrace`. So far, I have found out how to extract system call number and return value like this:

```
//In parent process
struct user_regs_struct regs;
ptrace( PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs ); 
//child_pid is the pid of child process executing the required program
//or system call passed as command line arguments
syscall_num = regs.orig_rax;
syscall_retval = regs.rax;
```

But I haven't been able to find how to extract system call name and arguments.
Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: you should go through the code of `strace()`, you'll get some idea. Besides, showing you what you asked here would actually need a very big answer.

Comment: Ok, I am, writing an answer for you, putting whatever i know. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the arguments of the system call you have to read the registers one by one. For that you need to know which registers will be storing which parameters of the system call. Few months back I had written one such program myself. Basically what each register stores is this:

> regs.rdi - Stores the first argument
>
> regs.rsi - Stores the second argument
>
> regs.rdx - Stores the third argument
>
> regs.r10 - Stores the fourth argument
>
> regs.r8  - Stores the fifth argument
>
> regs.r9  - Stores the sixth argument

This [table](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) presents a more elaborated description (notice that it's specific to x86-64 architecture).

Now, you have to go through the documentation of each system call to understand and code for them separately. There are different ways to read different arguments.

---

**Lets take the `read()` system call to demonstrate this.**

We will see the different kinds of arguments and see how to access them.

> 1st argument (int fd)

Since it is a number it will be saved directly in the register `regs.rdi`.

In my code, i needed to get the file to which that `fd` was pointing at so i used the following code.

```
sprintf(fdpath,"/proc/%u/fd/%llu",proc,regs.rdi);
size = readlink(fdpath, filepath, 256);  //this gives the filepath for a particular fd
filepath[size] = '\0';
printf("File-%s-\n", filepath);
```

> 2nd argument (void *buf) ptr to input buffer

To read this you would need to use `PTRACE_PEEKDATA` / `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` request (the first argument of `ptrace()`) to read the bytes. Since `ptrace()` reads and returns only `8` bytes at a time, you need to do this iteratively using a `long` variable. There should be another `char *` pointing in the beginning of the memory, that would be used later to read the string.

The code that I used is the following.

```
char message[1000];
char* temp_char2 = message;
int j = 0;
long temp_long;

while( j < (regs.rdx/8) ) //regs.rdx stores the size of the input buffer
{
    temp_long = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, proc, regs.rsi + (j*8) , NULL);
    memcpy(temp_char2, &temp_long, 8);
    temp_char2 += sizeof(long);
    ++j;
}
message[regs.rdx] = '\0';
printf("Message-%s-\n\n", message);
```

---

Thats all I can say. I guess you can read almost all the parameters of most of the system calls this way.

As for the name of the system call. I the OS mapping and made a manual `switch` case to get the name of the system call.

---

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: What about return values? Are they also stored that "easily" in a single register?

Comment: @traducerad, yes actually.. Its stored in the **regs.rax** register..

Answer (score 0):

I would map the regs.orig_rax against a const list of system calls, you can get the list from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.

if you want to know what are pointing the addresses of the registries, I suggest you read https://groogroot.eu/the-ptrace-system-call/ the method read_addr_into_buff, I did use it to read regs.rsi when a __NR_write SC was detected.